# How to create a 4 dimentional ndarray with the gray scale images of the series in the multiple subdirectories

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

In a directory (A), there exist 4 subdirectories (a,b,c,d), each of which contains 5 gray scale MRI images.
I could create a 3 dimensional ndarray in a subdirectory (a) by the following code.

```py
path = "./A/a"
list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):  
    for name in files:  
        list.append(os.path.join(root, name))  
list.sort() 
refds = pydicom.dcmread(list[0])
constpixeldims = (int(refds.Rows), int(refds.Columns), len(list))  
arraydicom = numpy.zeros(constpixeldims,dtype=refds.pixel_array.dtype)
for namedcm in list:
    ds = pydicom.dcmread(namedcm)  
    arraydicom[:,:,list.index(namedcm)] = ds.pixel_array
```

However, I want to create a 4 dimensinal ndarray with all 4 subdirectories.
By the 4 dimensional ndarray, I want to perform neural network analysis of MRI images.

[Another Question]
By the following code, I could create a 3 dimensional array.

```
for namedcm in dcmlist[0]:
ds = pydicom.dcmread(namedcm)  
arraydcm[:,:,dcmlist[0].index(namedcm)] = ds.pixel_array
```

Is it possible to create 4 dimensional array by changing of the nubmer of dcmlist from 0 to 3?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
import glob
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os


DIR = './A'

images = []
for sub_dir in os.listdir(DIR):
     print(sub_dir)
     images.append([cv2.imread(img) for img in glob.glob(DIR+os.sep+sub_dir+os.sep+'*')])


print(np.array(images).shape)
```

You'll get the following shape (if all the images are 160x160): (4,5,160,160).

If you want, for some reason, the shape (4,160,160,5), you can use [numpy.rollaxis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html):

```
images = np.rollaxis(np.array(images),1,4)
#images.shape -> (4,160,160,5)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I want to create a 4 dimensional array, in which axis=0 means the number of subdirectories, axis=1 and 2 mean the number of rows and columns of gray scale image pixels, and axis =3 means the number of images in a subdirectory. For example, array.shape --> (4,160,160,5)

Comment: Oh, i guess i missed your problem. I'll correct my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank your for your response. I could create a list, in which  keys were names of sub-directories and values were names of files, by following your response. However, I couldn't create a 4-dimensional array maybe because the image processing was unusual. "for namedcm in list:
    ds = pydicom.dcmread(namedcm)  
    arraydicom[:,:,list.index(namedcm)] = ds.pixel_array"

Comment: I added another question.